# option --plugin-path no longer exists error when using Python bindings of VLC

Tags: python, audio, video, vlc, libvlc

I have a folder containing the following files:

1) **VLC_Library_Test.py:** the code in it is shown below.
2) **vlc.py:** the vlc python bindings that I downloaded from http://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc/bindings/python.git;a=tree;f=generated;b=HEAD
3) **[Mazui]*Hyouka*-*13*[480p][DAEAD00A].mp4:** a video file that I wish to play using the script.

```
# contents of VLC_Library_Test.py
import vlc

file_path = 'C:\\Users\\JohnSmith\\Computer_Code\\Python\\VLC\\[Mazui]_Hyouka_-_13_[480p][DAEAD00A].mp4'
vlc_instance = vlc.Instance()
vlc_player = vlc_instance.media_player_new()

media = vlc_instance.media_new(file_path)

vlc_player.set_media(media)
vlc_player.play()
```

Whenever I run the VLC_Library_Test.py script, nothing happens and I get the following error in the console log:

```
Warning: option --plugin-path no longer exists.
Warning: option --plugin-path no longer exists.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

How can I get the script above to work and play the video file using VLC ?
Any help is appreciated.

Here is some information about my current system:

**Operating System:** Windows 7 Home Premium (64 bit)
**Python Interpreter:** Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:24) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
**VLC version:** 2.1.5 Rincewind (64 bit)
**vlc.exe & libvlc.dll Location:** C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a way to get it to work. All I needed was to add an infinite loop at the end of the code:

```
import vlc

file_path = 'C:\\Users\\JohnSmith\\Computer_Code\\Python\\VLC\\[Mazui]_Hyouka_-_13_[480p][DAEAD00A].mp4'
vlc_instance = vlc.Instance()
vlc_player = vlc_instance.media_player_new()

media = vlc_instance.media_new(file_path)

vlc_player.set_media(media)
vlc_player.play()

while True:
    pass
```

I also installed the latest 64 bit version of VLC (2.2.0 Weatherwax). I then created a system environment variable called VLC and assigned it a value of C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC (location of vlc.exe on your machine) and then appended that variable to the end of the system PATH variable. I had to restart Windows for the variable to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

Set the VLC_PLUGIN_PATH environment variable instead of using "--plugin-path".

Usually you don't have to set that variable, but I don't know the Python bindings for LibVLC.

Comment: I have created a system environment variable called VLC_PLUGIN_PATH and assigned it a value of C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\plugins. I then appended that variable to the end of the system PATH variable. I ran the script again but I still get the same error above.